# What's the best way to remove the last n lines of a file in a ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, file-io

I'm receiving a CSV file that always includes extra lines at the end which I'd like to remove before copying the data into the postgresql database of my rails app.

I can't use `head` with a negative argument because I'm on MacOS X.

What's a clean and efficient way to pre-process this file?

Right now I'm doing this, but am wondering if there is less mish-mash way:

```
# Removes last n rows from the file located at PATH
total = `wc -c < #{PATH}`.strip.to_i
chop_index = `tail -n #{n} #{PATH} | wc -c`.strip.to_i
`dd if=/dev/null of=#{PATH} seek=1 bs=#{total - chop_index}`
```

Comment: Are the files always small enough that they can be gulped into memory (using [CSV::read](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read), for example), or may they be so large that you must read them line-by-line? `n`, the number of lines at the end of the file to disregard, is fixed and known. Correct?

Comment: You do not wish to answer my questions?

Comment: CSV rows can span multiple lines. You need an actual CSV parser, not line-based tools like `head` or `tail`.

Comment: Cary, correct, the files can be quite large and the part at the end that needs to be removed is always the same.

Comment: That makes sense Stefan, but this is a very boring CSV. Just a plain text file with several tab-separated columns. Would rather not introduce the complexity of a CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the simplest way I can think to do this in pure ruby that also works for large files, since it processes each line at a time instead of reading the whole file into memory:

```
INFILE = "input.txt"
OUTFILE = "output.txt"

total_lines = File.foreach(INFILE).inject(0) { |c, _| c+1 }    
desired_lines = total_lines - 4

# open output file for writing
File.open(OUTFILE, 'w') do |outfile|
  # open input file for reading
  File.foreach(INFILE).with_index do |line, index|
    # stop after reaching the desired line number
    break if index == desired_lines

    # copy lines from infile to outfile
    outfile << line
  end
end
```

However, this is about twice as slow as what you posted on a 160mb file I created. You can shave off about a third by using `wc` to get the total lines, and using pure Ruby for the rest:

```
total_lines = `wc -l < #{INFILE}`.strip.to_i
# rest of the Ruby File code
```

Another caveat is that your CSV must not have it's own line breaks within any cell content, in which case, you would need a CSV parser, and `CSV.foreach(INFILE) do |row|` could be used instead, but it is quite a bit slower in my limited testing, but you mentioned above that your cells should be ok to be processes by file line.

That said, what you posted using `wc` and `dd` is much faster, so maybe you should keep using that.